# How can I work with the settings app of aosp?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I just started working on android open source project and I am trying to modify the settings application but when I am importing it with android studio and trying to compile I get this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
```

> /app/src/main/res/values-nl/strings.xml: Error: Found item String/sdcard_unmount more than one time

Seems like there are multiple statements of string such as

```
    <string name="sdcard_format" product="nosdcard" msgid="6285310523155166716">"USB-opslag wissen"</string>
<string name="sdcard_format" product="default" msgid="6713185532039187532">"SD-kaart wissen"</string>
```

It is causing errors, how can it be fixed?

Comment: aosp does not use gradle. it use make, and includes processing of the strings, in particular according to the product target (in this case, does the device have an sd card or not)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for answers, this other one in SO is much better: [Error:Error: Found item String/photoPickerNotFoundText more than one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541158/errorerror-found-item-string-photopickernotfoundtext-more-than-one-time/)

Answer (score -1):

you need to change the package name, because u r installing setting app on device which already have the setting app with same package name. you have to import the code modify it and then copy the new src and res directory in to aosp and create the image of android.

Comment: No, it's not the reason, I can't even build the app not to talk about running it, I get this error when I'm trying to build the app.

Comment: you can't compile the setting app by importing it into IDE. because there are some permissions in manifest that can be available to system app only. So, modify the setting app and build it with aosp build system only.

Comment: Is there a way to modify it in a proper ide?

Comment: Which is the exact IDE to use?. Because I am also facing this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59573510/how-to-run-the-individual-app-with-duplicate-product-attribute-in-strings-androi